# Tree with duplicate entries at leaves

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have data stored in the leaves of a tree. The leaves are accessed with a key that is a tuple of objects. The tree is potentially huge and I would like to condense it. For example:

```
        *
       / \
      a   b
     /|\   \
    1 2 5   1
   / /| |\  |\
  x x y x z y z   <-- Leaves
  | | | | | | |
  1 2 7 1 3 1 1   <-- Values at leaves
```

The tuples `(*, a, 1, x)` and `(*, a, 5, x)` both lead to the value of `1` at the leaves and so the tree can be condensed to:

```
        *
       / \
      a   b
     / \   \
    A   2   1
   /|  /|   |\
  x z x y   y z
  | | | |   | |
  1 3 2 7   1 1
```

where `A` represents a `1` or `5`. Of course, the look-up is slowed down by having to check for membership in the set `A`. I'm looking for a source that describes this data structure and related procedures.

I am using c++ in case anyone is inspired to share related code issues.

Comment: Sounds pretty similar to building something like a Patricia trie.

Comment: I may use something like that as part of condensing, but I need something more as well.

Comment: In what way is this a search tree?

Comment: I removed the search adjective. Thanks. (What should I call it?)

Comment: This is my understanding of your requirement. Let's say there are `h` levels starting from `1` to `h`. You merge two root to leaf paths if at each level (except for any 1 level) the elements in the paths are same

Comment: Is the depth of the tree constant (i.e. is the key tuple of constant arity?)

Comment: @arunmoezhi, I clarified what I am (was) looking for by adding a node to my diagram to show that it is not so much about merging paths together but merging subtrees together. That is if two (or more) nodes have the same lineage (i.e. have the same parent), then they can be merged together (as a set), their descendants being coalesced (as singletons) where appropriate, like the `x`'s in the diagram.

Comment: @sehe, I don't think that assumption needs to be made, but for the sake of simplicity, I would make that assumption. I ended up using a much different solution to the problem I was working on when I asked this question, but I'm still interested in learning.

Comment: I'm interested in learning how you approached it in the end :)

Comment: @thethuthinnang: I might have misunderstood, but I think you are trying to do something like path-compression

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are using the tree for, it is hard to make recommendations, but I believe that such a tree structure would never actually be useful in practice, since it is far easier to use some kind of sorted set or associative map than this.

However, if you already have the tree structure and want to keep efficiency exactly as it currently is, you can instead of merging branches replace all the leaves with pointers to the data. That way you can store each data object once and have multiple leaves pointing to the same data object. It is also the most flexible solution because you can still change the value of any leaf by simply changing the pointer, whereas in your idea of merging branches it cannot be undone without having a persistent data structure to begin with.